# R: Running stan() function get some errors:

Tags: r, rstan

when I am running the stan() function I get two errors about Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection and Error in sink(type = "output") : invalid connection. BTW, my .stan file is correct. Please help.

```
> rstan:::rstudio_stanc("8schools.stan")
8schools.stan is syntactically correct.
> schools_dat <- list(J = 8, 
+                     y = c(28,  8, -3,  7, -1,  1, 18, 12),
+                     sigma = c(15, 10, 16, 11,  9, 11, 10, 18))
> fit_8schools <- stan(file = 'C:/Users/.../Desktop/8schools.stan', data = schools_dat)
The NEXT version of Stan will not be able to pre-process your Stan program.
Please open an issue at
 https://github.com/stan-dev/stanc3/issues 
if you can share or at least describe your Stan program. This will help ensure that Stan
continues to work on your Stan programs in the future. Thank you!
This message can be avoided by wrapping your function call inside suppressMessages().
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In file.remove(c(unprocessed, processed)) :
  cannot remove file 'C:\Users\lpb\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpW6qdvg\file1f7436407ba4.stan', reason 'No such file or directory'
2: In system(cmd, intern = !verbose) :
  running command 'D:/ProgramFiles/R-4.0.2/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB file1f741c6e1040.cpp 2> file1f741c6e1040.cpp.err.txt' had status 1
3: In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'file1f741c6e1040.cpp.err.txt': No such file or directory
Error in sink(type = "output") : invalid connection

> setInternet2(TRUE) 
Error: 'setInternet2' is defunct.
See help("Defunct")
```

Comment: The setInternet2 part has nothing to do with rstan. see [Here](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-runtime-for-R/4.3.1/doc/html/Language_Reference/utils/setInternet2.html)

Comment: This is a problem with the toolchain or installation. Does `pkgbuild::has_build_tools(debug = TRUE)` return `TRUE`?

Comment: Yes，the return is TRUE. And then how can I deal with this problem